# Preprocessor Directive: #elif not defined?

Tags: c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Is there a preprocessor directive that checks whether a constant is not defined. I am aware of the `#ifndef` directive but I am also looking for a `#elif not defined` directive. Does `#elif not defined` exist?

This is how I would use it:

```
#define REGISTER_CUSTOM_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) \
    #ifndef CUSTOM_CALLBACK_1 \
        #define CUSTOM_CALLBACK_1 \
        FORWARD_DECLARE_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) \
    #elif not defined CUSTOM_CALLBACK_2 \
        #define CUSTOM_CALLBACK_2  \
        FORWARD_DECLARE_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) \
    #elif not not defined CUSTOM_CALLBACK_3 \
        #define CUSTOM_CALLBACK_3  \
        FORWARD_DECLARE_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) \
    #endif
```

Comment: `#elif not not defined CUSTOM_CALLBACK_3 ` not not defined?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You cannot define macros that contain other preprocessor directives. You cannot make `#define` or `#if` or `#elif` a part of a macro. Your macro has to be redesigned to make sure it has no inner "branching". All macro-branching has to be done "on the outside". It cannot be "embedded" into a macro.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about the

```
#elif !defined(...)
```

But you've got bigger problems - the trailing `\` exclude the other directives - or rather make them illegal. So, even with the valid syntax, your definitions won't do what you want.

You'll need to move the initial define inside the conditions.

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_CALLBACK_1
    #define CUSTOM_CALLBACK_1 
    #define REGISTER_CUSTOM_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) \
    FORWARD_DECLARE_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) 
#elif !defined(CUSTOM_CALLBACK_2)
    //.....
```